# how do I pick a link with empty class using cssSelector - Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

In my Selenium test I need to grab all the links inside a table that has empty class as shown below.

```
<td>
<a class="" href="" data-date="2016-11-18T00:00:00-05:00">18</a>
</td>
```

How do i achieve this using cssSelector ?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `"a[class='']"`.

Comment: muchas gracias @JeffC